# Send data from inner class

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a simple function to check if randomly generated string is in database, and if it is, generate a new one and check again. I'm using Firebase Databse, but my question is more about generic java. My code:

```
boolean check = true;
do {
String code = generateCode();
//Firebase way of reading data
ref.child(code).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) { 
                            check=false; //Doesn't work, check has to be final
                        }
} while(check);
```

Variable check can't be changed by inner class, but I need to send data from there. My question is how to do it correctly?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html

Comment: can you write the whole function ? Are you trying to return that boolean value with the function ? take in mind that this process is Asynchronous and you will be getting always true if you call your function

Comment: @Gastón Saillén It's mostly the whole function, there is only else cause saving data in databse if it doesn't exist. I know that I mixing async and sync here and It can lead to data corruption if it 2 people generate the same code at the same time, but chances of it are really small. Posted code doesn't work, check can't be changed and it's always true.

Comment: @fantaghirocco I tested AtomicBoolean, but it's still true. Probably because database check is asynchronous.